# Spark: How to define schema to read csv file with different number of columns?

Tags: csv, pyspark, stream, schema

I'm trying to read csv file with Pyspark. Csv-File has some meta-information and data columns, which have different column numbers and structures.

Excel has no Problem to read this file.
I would like to define a custom Schema in spark to read this file.
Here is an Example:

```
HEADER_TAG\tHEADER_VALUE
FORMAT\t2.00
NUMBER_PASSES\t0001
"Time"\t"Name"\t"Country"\t"City"\t"Street"\t"Phone1"\t"Phone2"
0.49tName1\tUSA\tNewYork\t5th Avenue\t123456\t+001236273
0.5tName2\tUSA\tWashington\t524 Street\t222222\t+0012222
0.62tName3\tGermany\tBerlin\tLinden Strasse\t3434343\t+491343434
NUM_DATA_ROWS\t3
NUM_DATA_COLUMNS\t7
START_TIME_FORMAT\tMM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
START_TIME\t06/04/2019 13:04:23
END_HEADER
```

Without pre-defined Schema spark read only 2 columns:

```
df_static = spark.read.options(header='false', inferschema='true', multiLine=True, delimiter = "\t",mode="PERMISSIVE",).csv("/FileStore/111.txt")

root
 |-- _c0: string (nullable = true)
 |-- _c1: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a custom schema:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *


# define it as per your data types
user_schema = StructType([
...    StructField("time", TimestampType(), True),
...    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
...    StructField("Country", StringType(), True),
...    StructField("City", StringType(), True),
...    StructField("Phone1", StringType(), True),
...    StructField("Phone2", StringType(), True),])
```

Refer: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.2/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/types.html

```
df_static = spark.read.schema(user_schema).options(header='false', multiLine=True, delimiter = "\t", mode="PERMISSIVE").csv("/FileStore/111.txt")
```

Comment: Can I read both meta-Information and data columns at once? Thank you!

Comment: So, It won't be possible in one step. Either parse the meta information first and then add data columns of a file, or vice versa. Because it is essentially one meta info for multiple data rows.

Answer (score -1):

I have multiple schemas like below

```
user_schema1 = StructType([
...    StructField("time", TimestampType(), True),
...    StructField("name", StringType(), True),
...    StructField("Country", StringType(), True),...   
...    ])

user_schema2 = StructType([...    
...    StructField("Phone1", StringType(), True),
...    StructField("Phone2", StringType(), True),])


df_static = spark.read.schema(user_schema(send schema name dynamic)).options(header='false', multiLine=True, delimiter = "\t", mode="PERMISSIVE").csv("/FileStore/111.txt")`enter code here`

Kindly provide me the solution
```